# Custom text field with syntax highlighting for c# in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2007, textfield

i need a text field in a sharepoint 2007 list that displays C# code with syntax highlighting.

Do i have to develop it on my own or knows somebody a control that meets my needs?

Thanks a lot

Comment: find something which looks usefull http://blog.graffen.dk/post/Enabling-code-syntax-highlighting-on-a-SharePoint-blog.aspx
and http://www.bartlannoeye.be/blog/2009/07/05/CodeSyntaxHighlightingInYourSharepointKnowledgeBase.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative for you is to use the javascript [SyntaxHighligher](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) library that can highlight just about every language on earth.

You would have to create your own custom control to render the field and output the javascript necessary to call the SyntaxHighlighter libraries.

http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/customizing-the-user-experience-of-sharepoint-custom-fields-deep-dive-part-5-of-6

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684919(office.12).aspx

http://vspug.com/nicksevens/2007/08/31/create-custom-field-types-for-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to create one. This control seems right for the job: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/ASPNET/CodeHighlighter/Default.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks more interessting. I tend to use your link.